# SQL how to return column values with same name only once

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing 3 columns consisting of a product (varchar), quantity(integer), price(integer). I want to get the total price of the products and return the product and the total price and ordered by descending alphabetical order. But if the product is repeated I only want to return the product once with its total price.

Heres the table:

| product | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pencil | 2 | 4 |
| Notebook | 3 | 5 |
| Notebook | 5 | 5 |

In this case desired output would be :

| product | totalprice |
| --- | --- |
| Notebook | 40 |
| Pencil | 8 |

My current output is this:

| product | totalprice |
| --- | --- |
| Notebook | 15 |
| Notebook | 25 |
| Pencil | 8 |

My query is the following:

```
SELECT product, quantity * price AS totalprice
FROM schoolproducts
ORDER BY product DESC
```

Comment: i am using oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for aggregation:

```
SELECT product, sum(quantity * price) AS totalprice
FROM schoolproducts
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY product DESC
```

Comment: oh I didnt know there was a 'sum' keyword. I tried it with GROUP BY but I was not getting the correct sum for 'Notebook'.